# Overwrite data frame value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have two data frame  df and ddff

df data frame have 3 row and 5 columns

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[0,1,0,0,1], [1,0,0,1,0], [0,1,1,0,0]]))
df

     0   1   2   3   4
0    0   1   0   0   1
1    1   0   0   1   0
2    0   1   1   0   0
```

ddff data frame consist of neighbour columns of a particular columns which have 5 row and 3 column where the value of ddff data frame represent the column name of df

```
ddff = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[3,2,1], [4,2,3], [3,1,4], [4,1,2], [2,3,1]]))
ddff

    0   1   2
0   3   2   1
1   4   2   3
2   3   1   4
3   4   1   2
4   2   3   1
```

Now I need a final data frame where where df column neighbour's set to 1 (overwrite previous value)

expected output

```
    0  1  2  3  4
0   0  1  1  1  0
1   1  0  0  1  0
2   0  1  1  0  0
```

Comment: I need to modify df data frame row 0 values based on ddff data frame. ddff data frame row 0 consist [3,2,1] values, Now If df data frame columns 3, 2 and 1 have value 0 then set it to 1

Comment: And for the row 1, 2, 3, 4 of ddff?

Comment: for now no need sir

Comment: so only row 0 matters? then you can use `df.loc[0, ddff.loc[0]] = 1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter the relevant column numbers from `ddff`, and set the values in those columns in the first row equal to 1 and set the values in the remaining columns to 0:

```
relevant_columns = ddff.loc[0]
df.loc[0,relevant_columns] = 1
df.loc[0,df.columns[~df.columns.isin(relevant_columns)]] = 0
```

Output:

```
   0  1  2  3  4
0  0  1  1  1  0
1  1  0  0  1  0
2  0  1  1  0  0
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
s = ddff.loc[0].values
df.loc[0] = np.where(df.loc[[0]].columns.isin(s),1,0)

>>> df

   0  1  2  3  4
0  0  1  1  1  0
1  1  0  0  1  0
2  0  1  1  0  0
```

---

Breaking it down:

```
>>> np.where(df.loc[[0]].columns.isin(s),1,0)
array([0, 1, 1, 1, 0])

# Before the update
>>> df.loc[0]
 0    0
1    1
2    0
3    0
4    1


# After the assignment back
0    0
1    1
2    1
3    1
4    0
```